# FacebookAuthenticatedContext returns a null Email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, authentication, owin

I have this problem with Facebook authentication, here are the following steps that we go through to encounter this problem:

- User A uses device A to register onto our app via Facebook
  authentication.
- User A successfully goes to the registration page with his first
  name, last name and email taken from Facebook authentication.
- User A registers.
- User A logs out of our app and also on Facebook.
- User B uses the same device as User A (device A) to register onto our
  app via Facebook.
- User B gets redirected to the login page every time he tries to use
  Facebook authentication.

So basically the problem is that the succeeding Facebook authentication using the same device has a problem. In the ExternalLoginCallback method, AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync returns a null every time for User B.

I tried changing the FacebookAuthenticationProviderOptions based on the solutions I found on the web but none of them worked. Here's the current code that I'm using:

```
string XmlSchemaString = "www.w3.org/.../XMLSchema";
        FacebookAuthenticationOptions options = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.AppId = "...";
        options.AppSecret = "...";
        options.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:email", context.Email, XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));
                foreach (var x in context.User)
                {
                    string claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", x.Key);
                    string claimValue = x.Value.ToString();
                    if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimType, claimValue, XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));
                    }
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        };
        options.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options);
```

In the previous code, the context was asnyc and this resulted AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync to return a null everytime for User B after following the steps above, this is the reason why it keeps landing on the login page averytime for User B, so I removed the async and context.Email results to a null.

For the record, if I try to login using Facebook for User A, it works fine. If anyone has encountered this problem, any help would be much appreciated. I have been trying to fix this for almost 3 days now and all fix I found and tried didn't work.

-----EDIT----

I found out the reason, there's an error if the email in the facebook account is not yet confirmed. Is there any workaround for this, our app needs the email information.

Thanks,

Comment: how did you figure out this. My app also need the email information

Comment: I'm using Email, PhoneNumber and Username,  so user have type them himself, or you've leave email  blank thats is not good idea.